# Spring - Dynamically injecting based on qualifier value

Tags: java, spring

In Weld, I can do the following to get dynamically inject config values from some source:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER })
public static @interface ConfigValue {

    @Nonbinding
    String value();
}

@Produces
@Dependent
@ConfigValue("")
public String stringValue(InjectionPoint ip) {
    ConfigValue configValue = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(ConfigValue.class);
    return myConfigMap.get(configValue.value());
}
```

The equivalent Spring, however, matches based on the value of the @ConfigValue annotation.

I would like Spring to call a method to allow me to inject custom values for all fields annotated with @ConfigValue.

I'm aware of this: http://joshlong.com/jl/blogPost/supporting_your_own_field_or_method_injection_annotation_processors_in_spring.html

However that's a very complex solution for a seemingly simple problem. I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution...

Comment: I seem to be missing the usecase? How is this not possible with either `@Value` or using the `Environment`?

Comment: @M.Deinum With the Weld example, I can inject a Provider<String> instead so that the "stringValue" function is called when getting the value. One of the use cases is looking up IP addresses of services in a service registry. If a service's IP changes, the bean should update its IP when needed. By having it call a function, this can be implemented along with any caching needed etc. Can `@Value` work like this? I would prefer to keep the same `@ConfigValue` javax.inject qualifier as we have some applications on Weld and some on Spring

Comment: Spring understand the `Provider` stuff as well, you should be able to `@Autowire` with `@Qualifier` that. If you want to auto wire your own custom annotations either extend the mechanism of spring or use composeable annotations (like annotating your annotation).

Answer (score 0):

Spring has [InjectionPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InjectionPoint.html) class. The catch is that your @ConfigValue annotation should not have [Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation. Then you can have a single method to produces various values.

However, if you choose to have @Qualifier on your @ConfigValue annotation, then you will have to have multiple producing methods one for each value of @ConfigValue. I dont seem to have come across anything equivalent to @Nonbinding though.

I have tested this for user object, not String.

PS: another approach is to have one "defining" annotation and one "non-defining" annotation on the injection point to serve your need.